# Output of python function isn't sorted

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have defined a function in Python which reads data from a non-sorted text file, sort the content by increasing order. I then ask the function to return the final variable.

When I call the function as part of another script the output of the function is in the "unsorted" state.

```
def read_file(my_file):
    import numpy as np
    initial_data =[]
    A = []
    B =  []
    C =  []
    D =  []
    with open(my_file) as f:
        for num, row in enumerate(f):
            initial_data.append(row[:])
            lines = row.strip()
            columns = lines.split()
            if num > 11:
                A.append(float(columns[0]))
                B.append(float(columns[1]))
                C.append(float(columns[2]))
                D.append(float(columns[4]))

    data = np.vstack((A,B, C,D)).T
    data= data[np.argsort(data[:,0])]

    return(data)
```

When i run this script alone the final `data` is sorted as per `data[np.argsort(data[:,0])]`.

But when I do:

```
new_data = read_file(my_file)
```

`new_data` is not sorted.

**EDIT:** I am using Python 3, `my_file` is a simple text file (.txt)

Comment: Can you tell the format of the data in text file. And which Python version are you using?

Comment: You need to write the sorted data in your file, otherwise your file will be left untouched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't know the reason for this, but I face the same problem and I know how to pass it. I solve the problem by replacing the "data" in the last line with new numpy array. I mean instead of this line

```
data= data[np.argsort(data[:,0])]
```

replace this two lines code

```
data1 = np.zeros(data.shape)
data1 = data[np.argsort(data[:,0])]
```

and finally return the data1.

Comment: I just tried, i still have the unsorted `data1` when called from another script :( . I am also using Spyder if it has any impact ?

Comment: Actually the trick was to restart Spyder for your solution to work! all good now :) @abolfazl taghribi